# Python: Trying to figure out Geopy in python for reverse look ups

Tags: python, reverse-geocoding, geopy

I am trying to test the following code on my system but I cannot get the correct output.

1. Is this code correct for using `geopy` with `GoogleV3`?
2. If so, how can I return country and continent name?

---

```
import subprocess
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

def set_proxy(proxy_addr):
    cmd = "set HTTPS_PROXY=" + proxy_addr
    call = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    cmd = "set HTTP_PROXY=" + proxy_addr
    call = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

set_proxy("my.proxy")

api_key = "my key"
geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key)
location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294", timeout = 10)
#would like to return just country and continent name
```

Comment: What output are you getting? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: @MaryBeth I want to return the country and continent (if possible) name for that lat long.

Comment: "I am trying to test the following code on my system but I cannot get the correct output."  What output are you receiving versus what are you expecting? If you are receiving an error, please post it. From our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour): *Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.*

Comment: What is the value of `location`, i.e has the reverse geocode been successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an external command to set your proxy.  If you are on Windows and your proxy is already setup in your internet options, you don't need to set it up in the script at all, it will be autodetected.

If you don't have a proxy already set up, you can pass the proxy directly to [the geocoder](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/#geopy.geocoders.GoogleV3):

```py
geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key, proxies={"http": proxy_addr, "https": proxy_addr})
```

Or you can set the proxy as an environment variable without an external command:

```py
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy_addr
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy_addr
geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key)
```

Then you can access the returned address like:

```py
location = geolocator.reverse([52.509669, 13.376294], timeout = 10, exactly_one=True)
print location.longitude,location.latitude,location.address
```

Output:

```
13.3756952 52.5102143 Potsdamer Platz 4, 10785 Berlin, Germany
```

If you want to extract the country name and post code, have a look in the `location.raw` dictionary. The response components are specified in the [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses).

```py
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

##################################################
# Some dummy values just so the script is
# self contained and runnable
api_key=None
rows=[{'avg_lat':52.509669, 'avg_lon':13.376294}]
##################################################

def get_component(location, component_type):
    for component in location.raw['address_components']:
        if component_type in component['types']:
            return component['long_name']

geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key)
for row in rows:
    location = geolocator.reverse((row['avg_lat'], row['avg_lon']), timeout = 10,  exactly_one=True)
    post_code = get_component(location, 'postal_code')
    country = get_component(location, 'country')

    print location.longitude,location.latitude,location.address
    print post_code,country
```

Note this is only applicable to the GoogleV3 geocoder and subject to breakage if Google changes their API...

Note - Google doesn't appear to return the continent name.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Been trying to get this to work weeks now

Comment: Luke, where is the documentation for accessing the raw components?

Comment: @dustin https://geopy.readthedocs.org discusses the `raw` dictionary

Comment: I was looking there but it wasn't verbose enough for me to understand. I couldn't find much on zip codes (postal codes) or how to access them if possible.

Comment: That's because `raw` is just the original response from the server parsed into a python dictionary. The response from each geocoding API will be different. You can use standard python techniques to inspect it,  i.e `print`, `location.raw.keys()`, `dir(location.raw)` etc...

Comment: @dustin, see edit to answer

Comment: Luke so for zip it would be:  `def get_zip(row):
        locations = geolocator.reverse(str(row['avg_lat']) + ', ' + 
        str(row['avg_long']), timeout = 10)
        for location in locations:
            for component in location.raw['address_components']:
                if 'postal_code' in component['types']:
                    return component['long_name']`

Comment: @dustin I wouldn't do it like that, unless the only thing you need from the location response is zip code. See edit

Comment: @dustin, please don't put code blocks in the comment area, [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/189312/edit) your question instead (you can add a comment as well so a notification is sent by the system).